# In C/C++, linked list has only head pointer allocated in stack and other nodes allocated in heap. This may cause memory leak?

Tags: c++, c, list, heap-memory, stack-memory

For C and C++, linked list with a pointer pointing to its head node. But, all nodes are allocated on heap by malloc() or new. When the head pointer runs out of its scope e.g. its function exits, all nodes allocated on heap will be lost. Right? Is this a memory leak?

How C/C++ handle this kind of issue? It calls deallocator automatically? (e.g. free() or delete)?

Comment: Yes, that's a memory leak, unless your pointers are all using shared_ptr or the like.

Comment: If any memory is explicitly allocated by new or malloc it needs to be explicitly destroyed by use of delete or free().  It is NOT cleaned up by function return.

Comment: "How C/C++ handle this kind of issue?" a programmer is responsible for memory management in C/C++

Comment: But the modern way to "to be responsible" is to use shared_ptr or it's like, or use value semantics and standard containers (or use standard containers with shared_ptr &c)

Comment: @Mordachai: To be fair, if you're actually implementing such a fundamental data structure, you wouldn't delegate the responsibility to yet another fundamental DS. Instead, you'll just have to think about it a bit and program it right. Not that it's trivial, but this is the level at which you *do* have to deal with lifetimes manually. (Though perhaps we can talk about using `unique_ptr`s of nodes.)

Comment: Pick a language, please. The answer for C++ is *vastly* different than the answer for C.

Comment: Actually, using a `unique_ptr` or similar in a linked list implementation is usually a really bad idea, because when you destroy the head, the destructors of each node in turn will pretty much inevitably end up calling each other call-recursively. So the size of your container is in effect limited by the size of your stack, although you don't find that out until cleanup time when your process explodes. This is a case where you want to manage it with unique ownership, and use loop-recursion to delete.

Comment: (You could achieve that by resetting the smart pointers in a sensible order, but if you have to disassemble the list manually anyway, you aren't really getting the benefit of a smart pointer, so it's just about as bad a situation as if you had to delete the nodes manually).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way to handle this sort of thing is to use a standard container, instead of some homespun thing, unless you have good reason & know what you're doing, and why...

std::vector<>
std::list<>

But to choose a container, it's important to know what you're doing, what the lifetime is supposed to be.

@Jack - no matter what you do, standard containers don't magically take care of manually allocated objects for you.  That is fundamentally impossible.

You must change your approach to the problem to perceive the problem as "manually allocated objects."  Once you make this leap, and realize that this is a bad way to go, then you can choose between "they're value-objects" or "they're to be managed by shared_ptr".

EX1: using shared_ptr to hold new'd objects (this is the approach to use if copying around MyNode is a bad idea [performance, owned resources, preserved state]):

```
void MyFunction()
{
  typedef boost::shared_ptr<MyNode> NodePtr;
  std::list<NodePtr> my_list;
  my_list.push_back(NodePtr(new MyNode(args...)));
  my_list.push_back(NodePtr(new MyNode(args...)));
  ...
  // when this function exits, the nodes, which are owned by shared_ptr's
  // which are themselves owned by a stack instance of std::list<> 
  // will be automatically deleted, no leaks anywhere...
}
```

EX2: This is what you do if your nodes are cheap, can be treated as copyable objects (value semantics):

```
void MyFunction()
{
  std::vector<MyNode> my_list;
  my_list.push_back(MyNode(args...));
  my_list.push_back(MyNode(args...));
  ...
  // when this function exits, the nodes, which are shored directly as copies
  // in the vector container, will be automatically deleted, no leaks anywhere...
}
```

And if you really would rather manage the instances manually for some reason (usually you do this because the lifetimes are not really tied to a single container's lifetime, but have some irregular lifecycle that cannot be encapsulated neatly by anything but a custom algorithm):

```
void MyFunction()
{
  std::list<MyNode*> my_list;
  my_list.push_back(new MyNode(args...));
  my_list.push_back(new MyNode(args...));
  ...
  // we must manually deallocate the nodes because nothing else has been given
  // responsibility anywhere (we're manually managing them)
  typedef std::list<MyNode*>::iterator iterator;
  for (iterator it = std::begin(my_list), end = std::end(my_list); it != end; ++it)
    delete *it;  // manually releases our allocated memory from the heap
  // the "head" is still deleted automatically because it is stack allocated
  // (the list object)
}
```

Comment: I do not think a std container can handle the memory leak automatically. For example, std::list<int*> myList. myList.push_back(ptr1), myList.push_back(ptr2). After myList's function exists, the memory pointed by ptr1 and ptr2 are all lost. This is memory leak. If we change int* to shareed_ptr<int>, this issue can be fiex ?

Comment: Or, what if shared_ptr<int> myPtr = &myList.front() ? this may solve the problem.

Comment: Not if you put raw pointers in, no.  But that's saying "I will manually manage the lifetimes of your contained objects."  If you want the library to handle it, either use value objects (copyable), or use shared_ptr to embed them in a container & not worry about lifetimes.

Comment: @Jack you cannot just assign the head of your linked list to a standard list and expect that to make any difference.  I'll add a manually managed solution to the above in case that helps you...

Answer (score 0):

If you no longer have a way to access the nodes (and they are still in memory), then yes, that it a leak. The language itself does not handle memory leaks in any way, however modern operating systems do cleanup after a process has ended, so the memory leaks do (eventually) get solved, but only at the end of the process' execution. (However, do not rely on the OS to clean up after you — that's a horrible thing to do as a programmer.)

Comment: But this is a terrible thing to rely upon.  It's not sound programming (but it is useful to be aware of).

Comment: @Mordachai: although, you know when you shut down a program that you haven't touched in a while, and it chugs like anything before finally disappearing? A significant amount of that time is because "sound programming" dictates that it should churn through all of its allocated memory, summoning it out of disk cache in order to free it. Sometimes for a large apps, a good option is just to exit the process in release mode, but perform frees in debug mode so that your leak-checker can find the genuine bugs. C++ makes that pretty difficult, of course, it's more feasible in C apps.

Comment: @SteveJessop There are ways to handle this w/o just abandoning objects.  And I would be okay with choosing very carefullly amongst those objects you were choosing to abandon in this way, since you must ensure that such objects do not themselves hold resources beyond RAM.  This is surely an advanced topic of industrial software design, and not something to throw around for "How do I..." basic C++ conversation / question :)

Comment: @Mordachai Of course, relying on the OS to clean up after you is not acceptable, but the OP asked what happens with the leaked memory. :)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is a memory leak. No, neither C nor C++ (there is not such language as C/C++) has not any mechanisms to handle this. They are not JAVA or later language. It is up to YOU, as a coder.

Comment: C++ *does* have a way of cleaning it up, otherwise the documented behaviour of `std::forward_list` would be a lie